# Going through linked scroll view content how to spot when its finished. UI automation

Tags: algorithm, automation, linked-list

I am wondering what would be a stable algorithm that can determine a length of a scrollable carousel.

For example i have a view with left andright button that can go through the whole collection of items.

The items can be repetitive and non-unique. For example :

A<->B<->C<-D->A<->B<->C<->H<->G ( G is connected to A with <->)

Using a bot that can inspect the state and click,

**how many times i need to go through the whole list to determine that is the final one** ?

thanks

Comment: You can never be sure you have the final one because if you cannot identify uniquely the elements you can never be sure the cycle ended..

Comment: yeah i realise that but isn't there any backup strategy like assuming the max list cannot be more than 200 ?

Comment: Than make 200 calls and detect the smallest cycle matching your 200 events observation.